# How to get rid of double column table in return data from select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

```
Tasks[id_task,task_title,author,id_project]
SubTasks[id_subtask,subtask_title,author,id_task]
```

And I use this query to return data:

```
Select PS.task_title as subtask_category, PS.id_task, PS.id_project, P.* 
  From SubTasks P inner join Tasks PS 
    on P.id_task=PS.id_task 
 where PS.id_project = 1  
 order by PS.id_task desc
```

The problem is that the result table contains duplicate id_task column, how can I resolve this?

Comment: Remove PS.id_task from the select list (since id_task is a part of P.*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that the SubTasks table is always going to have id_task (which you do because of the join) remove `PS.id_task` from the select so it will only be grabbed by the `P.*`

Answer (score 0):

Change your `SELECT` clause to be `SELECT PS.id_task, PS.task_title, PS.author, PS.id_project, P.id_subtask, P.subtask_title, P.author` and leave off the `P.id_task`. Your `P.*` is telling the query to return all columns in the SubTasks table, when you've already told the query earlier to return PS.id_task in the Tasks table.